# Whatsapp "address_message" type interactive message is not opening

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm trying to send an interactive message on Whatsapp, of type "address_message", as per the Facebook documentation given below.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/messages/address-messages

Here is my request payload:

```
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "recipient_type": "individual",
    "to": "91xxxxxxxxxx",
    "type": "interactive",
    "interactive": {
        "type": "ADDRESS_MESSAGE",
        "body": {
            "text": "Thanks for your order! Tell us what address you’d like this order delivered to."
        },
        "action": {
            "name": "address_message",
            "parameters": {
                "country": "IN"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to receive the message on the given WhatsApp number. But the form to input the address opens up on my number only and throws an error on all other numbers saying - "The link you are trying to access is not working".

NOTE: All these numbers are Indian.

Comment: And those "other numbers" are actually from the - very limited - regions where this is available?

Comment: Updated the question. All these numbers are Indian and supported for address type message as per Facebook documentation.